# How to install pkg file in Win8?

Tags: windows, installation, package

Not find any way to install this file from the Windows 8!
What can I do?

Search previous questions, but could not resolve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a step-by-step procedure to get pkg-config working on Windows, based on my experience, using the info from Oliver Zendel's comment.

I assume here that MinGW was installed to C:\MinGW. There were multiple versions of the packages available, and in each case I just downloaded the latest version.

1. go to http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/
2. download the file pkg-config_0.26-1_win32.zip
3. extract the file bin/pkg-config.exe to C:\MinGW\bin
4. download the file gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win32.zip
5. extract the file bin/intl.dll to C:\MinGW\bin
6. go to http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/glib/2.28
7. download the file glib_2.28.8-1_win32.zip
8. extract the file bin/libglib-2.0-0.dll to C:\MinGW\bin

Now CMake will be able to use pkg-config if it is configured to use MinGW.